# My Zelda does not save after beating Ganon in botw

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Confused why happening pls respond I’ve done the Ganon fight twice it never saves

Answer (score 9):

Been a while since I beat the game but I think it doesn't give you an option. Your savefile will never be 'beaten' because it doesn't save after the fight.

Pretty sure there is no state in the game where you can run around but ganon has been defeated.

So basically there is no game 'after ganon is defeated'. So after the credits roll and you reload your save you will be before the fight. Run back out of the castle and continue to roam.

TLDR: It's not a bug. It just doesn't let you save after the final fight.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is the correct answer.

Comment: If you go to the main menu to load a game, it will put a start next to the save file of any game that has completed the final boss fight, so it does record that you have beaten Ganon even though it returns you to before the fight.